# Unable to set custom Picklist value from Class to VF page

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am having a small issue while assigning a value to custom picklist in my VF.

I am storing values (0 or 1) in a custom field (`Match_Filter__c`).

With my logic I am able to get the value of above custome field, and also able to assign it  to `crit.reportingMatch`.

But, still the value of`crit.reportingMatch` isn't upadting with the value which we set in class. It is still showing '- Reporting Match Filter -' in VF page.

Our expected result is : If `crit.reportingMatch` is 1 or 0, cutom picklist also shoud be updated accordingly.

**VF**

```
<apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
   <apex:outputText >Match Filter</apex:outputText>
   <apex:selectList value="{!crit.reportingMatch}" size="1">  
      <apex:selectOptions value="{!crit.reportingMatchPicklist}"/>
   </apex:selectList>
</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
```

**Controller Class**

```
public with sharing class massOppController {

    public massOppCriteria Crit{get; set;}

// Assigning filterRec.Match_Filter__c value(either 0 or 1) to crit.reportingMatch
crit.reportingMatch = String.valueOf(filterRec.Match_Filter__c);
```

**massOppCriteria Class**

```
public String reportingMatch {get;set;}

public static LIST<SelectOption> getReportingMatchPickList() {
        List<SelectOption> reportingMatchPickList = new List<SelectOption>();
        reportingMatchPickList.add(new selectoption('', '- Reporting Match Filter -'));
        reportingMatchPickList.add(new selectoption('0', '0'));
        reportingMatchPickList.add(new selectoption('1', '1'));
        return reportingMatchPickList;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is that the value of `filterRec.Match_Filter__c` is null. This can occur if the value has not yet been set. If it is null then the following line results in `crit.reportingMatch` being assigned null.

```
crit.reportingMatch = String.valueOf(filterRec.Match_Filter__c);
```

If that happens, the first SelectOption in the list of `crit.picklist` will be displayed.  In your case the first SelectOption is `- Reporting Match Filter -`.

I suggest adding in some System.debug statements to the controller to track the value of `filterRec.Match_Filter__c`.

Answer (score 0):

I somehow found the issue.

I had to refresh the section where we have the Picklist field.
so I addde that section in `rerender` attribute of the component.